# How to manage a Huge Sprite

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, png, sprite

Currently I'm on a website for a client and they would like the lab to allow the user to design fully customized gaming controllers. In order to reduce the number of loads and make things faster I decided to put all the images into 1 massive sprite. While on a fast connection there is only a few seconds of wait time the slower connections could be minutes.

The sprite I'm dealing with it 4305x3945, ~15MB, and prone to grow even larger as more options are added. As a side note the client wants PS4, Xbox 360, and Xbox One offered which would require 3 sprites of similar size (only loaded with requested).

Currently I just load the whole sprites and use drawImage cutting out the section I need and it's very fast.

So I guess my question is what would be the most efficient way to go about reducing the load time? Should I allow users to use a semi-functional lab once say ~40% of the options load? Should I have a basic sprite half the size and offer an option to load more shells (in another sprite)? Or should I separate all the images into their own files and only load when that specific item is needed (~0.2-2.5sec per shell)?

Here is what the largest sprite looks like:

[image: Sprite]

Comment: .jpg instead of .png while the user is designing and then ajax .png the user's final choice?

Comment: I would like to keep the transparent background if possible. Otherwise the none square objects will have weird renedering colors. Or should I have canvas manipulate pure white pixels to be invisible?

Comment: Could you get the original files, which must be vector format, and vector files might be must cheaper. If you handle the color (/color gradient) separately; you can have only one vector file, then you add the color on draw.

Comment: @Steven10172 Jpeg often has no purely-white pixels near contrast edges. Using color-keying on jpeg's would likely look even worse.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I have the original files. Its just 1 controller shell with modified hues, and other stuff, in Photoshop to look like different colors, but retain the same exact shape.

Comment: @GameAlchemist the original is not vector. He takes a picture of the controller with his camera and them modifies them in Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, most of your sprites are just color variations.

You can save lots of bandwidth by having just a single greyscale graphic which you colorize into different hues at runtime.

In order to do that, you can use `context.getImageData()` to get an array of the raw RGBA values of a canvas (or part of it), modify the RGB values, and write them to another canvas with `context.putImageData()`.

[The documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#pixel-manipulation) tells you more about how to use these functions.

Another thing you could do is use vector graphics in the SVG format instead of raster-graphics in PNG. It's hard to tell with such a downscaled sample-graphic, but it seems like most of your graphics are quite geometric. The filesize of SVG graphics doesn't depend on size, only on level of detail. When your graphics are indeed very stylized, representing them in SVG could save much bandwidth over PNG.

Comment: The sample image is a bit small (and someone crisscrossed through it ) but there seem to be a few pattern variations. Also note row 3, column 3: a rainbow design. OTOH: the patterns can easily be overlaid over the plain-colored base. Definitely worth a try, I'd say.

Comment: @Steven10172 updated answer with alternative solution (using SVG)

Comment: I really like this answer. I've been actually meaning to do something exactly like this for most simple shells and only loading the image based shells (or giving use options to load more).

Comment: I like the theory of this answer (replace color variations on the client-side).  It seems well suited to mono-color shells (no rainbow and no gradients).  However, most of the shells in your image actually have gradients which would not be well-suited to client side color substitution.  BTW, svg is often *larger* than .png when given gradients.  For example, I took your .png sample and vectorized it in Adobe Illustrator: .png = 89 kb, .svg = 1.1 mb. Anyway, that's my 2-cents.  Good luck with your project :)

Comment: @markE That's wrong. The SVG format supports gradients just fine. But automatic vectorizers often have trouble to recognize gradients as such and try to represent them with many individual shapes. It's obvious that this will result in a huge file-size. When you design a graphic in vector-format from the start, it will be **much** more efficient than when you try to auto-reverse-engineer the vectors from a bitmap.

Comment: @markE Also note that the demo graphic is downscaled from a much larger image. When the original resolution would be 10x10 of the thumbnail, it would take about 100 times the file-size in a raster format. But vector graphics are resolution-independent. Their filesize doesn't change, no matter how much you upscale or downscale them.

Comment: +1 @Philipp: As I said, I like the svg version of your answer—and I’m warming up to it even more as I examine it further! ;)    I’m concluding that 1.1mb per set of 39 controllers is a download size that even mobile phone users would accept without abandoning their shopping trip on the site--especially since the same .svg will display thumbs & full-size.  I assume the reworking of the art from raster to vector is not a burden.

Comment: @Philipp: Not to be hard-headed, but I think my 1.1mb is a good estimate of the size of 39 svg controllers.  I pulled an example of an svg conroller image.  The non-changing part (the paths) == 10k.  The changing parts (gradients,filters) == 30k each controller.  So for 39 controllers that’s 10k + 39 x 30k == 1.18mb.  Link: http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/1/e/6/1348002009949283353Game%20Controller.svg.